# почему не читается иконка?

Tags: python, tkinter

такой код работает:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *

root=Tk()
image = PhotoImage(file='image.png')
button=Button(root, image=image)
button.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

а такой не срабатывает, почему???

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        image = PhotoImage(file='image.png')
        self.button1=Button(root, image=image)
        self.button1.pack()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app = Main(root)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2):

Думаю, потому что объект картинки передается в кнопку по ссылке, а там не копируется - с ним так и работают по ссылке (что логично, чтобы не засорять память и занимать ресурсы проца, картинки бывают весьма тяжелые). В первом случае ваша картинка живет пока живет приложение, во-втором - в локальной (стековой) памяти метода init_main (до выхода их него).

Поэтому надо чтобы ссылка на картинку не удалялась сборщиком мусора, а жила все необходимое время.

Для этого надо, либо сделать ссылку на картинку полем класса:

```
class Main(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, root):
        super().__init__(root)
        self.image = PhotoImage(file='image.png')
        self.init_main()

    def init_main(self):
        self.button1=Button(root, image=self.image)
        self.button1.pack()
```

И тогда картинка будет жить пока живет объект класса.

Либо, передавать ссылку на картинку из вне класса Main:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    image = PhotoImage
    app = Main(root, image)
    app.pack()
    root.mainloop()
```

В этом случае картинка будет жить до выхода из цикла `root.mainloop()`.

Первый вариант лучше, если картинка нужна только в одном классе, второй - если она нужна нескольким объектам приложения.